# getting error when i set slotMinutes to 50 value in jquery fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

i am working with jquery fullcalendar resource view.
and i want to set slotMinutes to 50.

but when i set it than its not displaying events.

and its giving error in this function :

function HorizontalPositionCache(getElement)

and line is :

```
    t.left = function(i) {      
    return lefts[i] = lefts[i] === undefined ? e(i).position().left : lefts[i];
};
```

error is : TypeError: e(...).position(...) is null

Can anyone help me please to resolve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HorizontalPositionCache is one of your functions or is it from `FullCalendar`?

Comment: It is a function from fullcalendar.js

Comment: Take a look at this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/jarnokurlin/fullcalendar/issues/45 I think the problem mentioned there may have something related to this problem...

Answer (score 0):

On file **fullcalendar.min.js** edit the function **function timeOfDayCol(datetime)**

Before of the return, put:

**colCnt = Math.floor( (24 * 60) / slotMinutes);**

The function will stay like:

```
function timeOfDayCol(datetime) {
        var hours = datetime.getHours();
        var minutes = datetime.getMinutes();
        var slotMinutes = opt('slotMinutes');
        var slot, diff, minDiff, closestMinute;

        // round minutes to closest minuteslot
        for (var i = 0; i <= 60 / slotMinutes; i++) {
            slot = i * slotMinutes;

            diff = Math.abs(slot - minutes);

            if (diff <= minDiff || i == 0) {
                minDiff = diff;
                closestMinute = slot;
            }

            if (closestMinute == 60) {
                hours++;
                closestMinute = 0;
            }
        }
        minutes = closestMinute;



        for (var i = 0; i < colCnt; i++) {
            if (indexDate(i).getHours() == hours && indexDate(i).getMinutes() == minutes) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        // not in range, return max
        colCnt = Math.floor( (24 * 60) / slotMinutes);

        return colCnt;
    }
```